# ¿Validar ventana modal cuando hay un error en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que estoy desarrollando un aplicativo en laravel que hasta el momento me permite realizar un crud completo de clientes, para crear y editar clientes hago uso de ventanas modales de bootstrap y jquery, el problema que presento es que en el controlador hago uso del $this->validate, para hacer las validaciones respectivas del formulario que se encuentra en las ventanas modales, cuando ocurre un error en el ingreso de datos el $this->validate me retorna a la misma vista y me muestra el error en el formulario, pero en este caso que,  estoy usando ventanas modales tuve que hacer un condicional en la vista blade, para que cuando ocurriera un error de validacion me retornara a la misma vista y me abriera el modal para visualizar el error, esta validacion es la siguiente:

```
{{-- Con este condicional abrimos el modal si hay un error de validacion en el backend --}}
     @if($errors->any())
    <script>
        $('#createclient').modal('show');
    </script>
    @endif
```

El problema es que ahi solo esta funcionando con el modal de crear cliente. ¿como podria validar que, cuando hay un error en el formulario de crear me retorne a la vista con el modal de crear abierto y cuando hay un error en el formulario de editar me retorne a la vista con el modal de editar abierto?

les adjunto el codigo de la vista blade completa:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


@section('content')


<div class="container" style="text-align:right">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createclient">
        Añadir cliente
    </button>

</div>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Modal para agregar cliente -->
    <form action="{{ route('client.create') }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="modal fade" id="createclient" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Crear cliente</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">                      

                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <strong>Nombre del cliente</strong>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del cliente" required>
                            <br> {{ $errors->first('name') }}

                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <strong>Correo del cliente</strong>
                            </span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Ingrese el correo del cliente" required>
                            <br> {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">



        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>

                    <th scope="col">NOMBRE</th>
                    <th scope="col">CORREO</th>
                    <th scope="col">Acciones</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($client as $cliente)
                <tr>

                    <td>{{ $cliente->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $cliente->email }}</td>
                    <td>

                        <button type="button" data-id="{{ $cliente->id }}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editar_{{$cliente->id}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </button>

                        <!-- Modal para editar cliente -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="editar_{{$cliente->id}}" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <form action="{{ route('client.update',$cliente->id) }}" method="POST">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Editar cliente</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="container-fluid">

                                                <input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $cliente->id }}" hidden>
                                                <span class="input-group-text">
                                                    <strong>Nombre del cliente</strong>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $cliente->name }}" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del cliente" required>
                                                <br> {{ $errors->first('name') }}

                                                <span class="input-group-text">
                                                    <strong>Correo del cliente</strong>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ $cliente->email }}" placeholder="Ingrese el correo del cliente" required>
                                                <br> {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                                                <input type="text" name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}" hidden>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {{-- boton para eliminar --}}
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('client.destroy', $cliente->id) }}" style="display:inline">

                            {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro de querer eliminar este cliente?')">
                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </button>


                        </form>



                    </td>


                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
    {{-- Con este condicional abrimos el modal si hay un error de validacion en el backend --}}
     @if($errors->any())
    <script>
        $('#createclient').modal('show');
    </script>
    @endif 
    @stop
```

Tambien adjunto las funciones de crear y editar del controlador por si acaso:

funcion store para crear:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:clients,email'

         ]);

        toastr()->success('Correctamente', 'Cliente creado', [
            'timeOut' => 2000,
            'positionClass' => "toast-top-full-width",
            'progressBar' => false,
            'showDuration'=> 300,
            ]);

        //De esta forma se inserta tambien el id del usuario al que pertenece el cliente en la bd
        auth()->user()->client()->create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('client.list');
    }
```

funcion update para actualizar o editar el cliente:

```
  public function update(Request $request, Client $client)
    {
        //Consultamos el email perteneciente al cliente
        $email = $client->email;

        //Si el email que llega por request, es igual al de la base de datos
        if ($request->email == $email) {
            $request->request->remove('email');
        }


        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'unique:clients'
        ]);

        toastr()->info('Correctamente', 'Cliente editado', [
            'timeOut' => 2000,
            'positionClass' => "toast-top-full-width",
            'progressBar' => false,
            'showDuration'=> 300,
            ]);


        return redirect()->route('client.list');
    }
```

Comment: creo que no se puede vas a tener que integrarle a tu modal jqueryvalidation o similares para que pare el formulario en caso de error e igual que cancele el cerrado del modal, ya asi hasta que este correcto que permita su acceso.

Comment: retornar un valor que indique si es `editar` o `crear`, o ponerlo en una variable de sesión, en la vista levantas esa variable/valor y abrís el modal correspondiente

Comment: podrias dar un ejemplo?

Comment: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-55-crud-example-from-scratchexample.html aqui puedes encontrar como hacer tu crud en laravel

Comment: ???????????????????

Answer (score 0):

tengo un ejemplo y espero que le funcione: 
este es un campo que lo estoy realizando dentron de modal  con el modal

```
 <div class='form-group' id='descripcion' >
        <label class='control-label col-sm-2' for='descripcion'>descripcion:</label>
           <div class='col-sm-10'>
               <input type='text' class='form-control' id='descripcion_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>
                    <p class='errornombre text-center alert alert-danger hidden'></p>
           </div>
</div>
```

**en el archivo js se hace la peticion en ajax**  en la par

```
  success: function(data) { 
            $('.errorid').addClass('hidden');$('.errornombre').addClass('hidden');$('.errormunicipios_id').addClass('hidden');$('.errorcreated_at').addClass('hidden');$('.errorupdated_at').addClass('hidden');;
            if ((data.errors)) {
                    //setTimeout(function () {      
                        $('#massModal').modal('show');
                    //  toastr.error('Validation error!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                    //}, 500);
            if(data.errors.id){$('.errorid').removeClass('hidden');$('.errorid').text(data.errors.id);
            }
            if(data.errors.nombre){$('.errornombre').removeClass('hidden');$('.errornombre').text(data.errors.nombre);
            }
        } else {
            Alert("si paso");
            toastr.success('Successfully added Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});

        }
    }
```

en el controlador lo tengo de la siguiente forma

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');



    }
    /**
    * @var array
    */
    protected $rules =
    [

                //'id' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                'consecutivo' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                'asistencias_estado_id' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                'barrio_id' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                'usuario_id' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                'vereda' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'telefono' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                'concepto' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'agricola' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'pecuaria' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'forestal' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'ambiental' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'dianosticos' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'recomendaciones' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'usuario_umata' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',

    ];
```

en una funcion esta asi

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $this->rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        } else {
            $Asistencia = AsistenciaModel::findOrFail($id);

             $Asistencia->consecutivo=$request->consecutivo;
                 $Asistencia->asistencias_estado_id=$request->asistencias_estado_id;
                 $Asistencia->barrio_id=$request->barrio_id;
                 $Asistencia->usuario_id=$request->usuario_id;
                 $Asistencia->vereda=$request->vereda;
                 $Asistencia->telefono=$request->telefono;
                 $Asistencia->concepto=$request->concepto;
                 $Asistencia->agricola=$request->agricola;
                 $Asistencia->pecuaria=$request->pecuaria;
                 $Asistencia->forestal=$request->forestal;
                 $Asistencia->ambiental=$request->ambiental;
                 $Asistencia->dianosticos=$request->dianosticos;
                 $Asistencia->recomendaciones=$request->recomendaciones;
                 $Asistencia->usuario_umata=$request->usuario_umata;
                 $Asistencia->created_at=$request->created_at;
                 $Asistencia->updated_at=$request->updated_at;


            $Asistencia->save();
            return response()->json($Asistencia);
        }
    }
```